# GeoListPlot: GeoLabels

Tags: curated-data, geography, geographics

```
GeoListPlot[AirportData[{"ORD"}], GeoLabels -> True]
```

shows correctly a red point, labeled `"Chicago O'Hare Internation Airport"`.

Is it possible to label that point by the airports IATA-Code, which is already a property of `AirportData[]`?

Thanks Volker

Answer (score 8):

The [`GeoLabels` docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoLabels.html) says that it accepts a function of the form

```
function[graphics_, region_, position_]
```

when used in `GeoListPlot`. A little experimentation shows that `region` is the `Entity`, itself, e.g.

```
GeoListPlot[AirportData[{"ORD"}], GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#1, #2]&)]
```

So, we can then use that info to create the IATA-Code label,

```
GeoListPlot[AirportData[{"ORD"}], 
  GeoLabels -> ({Black, Text[#2["IATACode"], #2, {0, -1}]} &)]
```

[image]